# Add maven dependency conditional on another

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have several projects that depend on a common framework, built on top of Spring Boot. This framework autoconfigures lots of the things that applications use via `BeanPostProcessor` and similar Spring mechanisms.

It also adds support for optional libraries that the applications can use, using `@Conditional` beans and optional Maven dependencies.

The problem I'm facing is that one of those optional libraries is Resilience4J and I'd like to add a dependency on `resilience4j-micrometer` if Resilience4j is added, so I can expose out-of-the-box all Resilience4J metrics via Micrometer.

Is there any mechanism in Maven that allows to add a conditional dependency given some condition, so I ensure that every application using Resilience4J exposes its metrics?

PS: I tried to just create a module to wrap the dependencies, but there are different Resilience4J dependencies the applications use (some apps are web and others Webflux, some use the Spring Cloud abstraction and others don't...).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manage dependencies via maven profile but it not really the best way. Your framework should integrate all libraries and your app manage dependencies with exclusions in order that Spring Boot can autoconfigure only included dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, that's another option but it's worse than simply adding the micrometer dependency (given people already have to remember to touch the dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following your question, I assume that you have a library "common".
So you have an application A (spring boot driven), and in its pom.xml you add a dependency on "common". You would like to create Beans in the application context of A if A has a dependency on Resilience4J. These beans are supposed to add expose some micrometer related stuff.

In this case you could probably use [ConditionalOnClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html):

In "common"'s code you could have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Resilience4j.class) // or whatever class that can indicate that resilience4j is in the classpath, I took this for the sake of example, I don't know whether this class really exists
public class CommonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public YourMicrometerIntegrationBean yourMicrometerIntegrationBean() {
      return new YourMicrometerIntegrationBean();
    }

    .. other beans ..
}
```

This solution assumes that you have a dependency (optional ?) at the level of maven in "commons" to resilience4j. If you don't want this for some reason, you could create your custom condition (I believe you know how to do that based on the details that you've supplied in the question you have a pretty advanced setup, let me know if you need more details on that), and this custom condition will evaluate to "true" if `Class.forName(<FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_RESILIENCE_4_J>)` won't throw an exception so that you'll see that its available in runtime.

Comment: The Conditional part is fine, indeed we have plenty of `@ConditionalOnClass` usage (including Resilience4J). The problem is that `resilience4j-micrometer` doesn't use optional dependencies, so it will bring the dependencies for Resilience4J. I was asking if there's a way of adding the maven dependency on `resilience4j-micrometer` on the framework pom given only in the cases that Resilience4J dependencies are added by the application. So mainly the same concept as `@ConditionalOnClass` but for Maven dependencies

Comment: No, because maven is a build tool but spring boot runs in runtime. So basically you should build artifact once in maven, and in runtime load the relevant beans by understanding what exactly happens in the classpath... So I don't think you should rely on maven here. Well, technically there are maven profiles that can slightly alter the build depending on environment, os, java version, properties and so forth, but I would say its an abuse of the feature in this case. Having said that I don't totally understand what do you want to achieve. Do you build framework many times - per  micro-service?

Comment: We have a single framework, for all applications, and it's built separately and then used as a Spring Boot starter. But we don't impose stuff like what circuit breaker should be used or if any at all. For that, we still offer some support. For example, we have conditional error handling for Hystrix and Resilience4J, so we can intercept outgoing exceptions and unwrap them from the Hystrix/Resilience4J specific exceptions. So we can still treat a, let's say NPE, even if it happens inside a circuit-breaker decorator. All that is done with optional maven dependencies and Spring conditionals

Comment: Ok, I understand, so you have one build job for the framework. When the framework artifact is build you, say publish it on Nexus, so that other teams who develop their microservices can add a dependency on this framework. But if so, the framework is already built when you consume it. If you declare a dependency on framework you'll get its jar regardless of whether you have resilience4j in the microservice or not. You can't bring only a part of jar in maven if I understood your question... More than that, then the  microservice is built, maven is not even running...

Comment: If the goal is minimation of the dependant code - you can split the framework into small parts (jars) pretty much like spring boot does, so that each part will have its own starter and the developer of the microservice would decide what parts of the framework to bring. Other than that I don't understand what can you achieve with the "conditional dependency"... I might be missing something though

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to provide Resilience4J metrics support out-of-the-box. The same way I support the exceptions without imposing the circuit-breaker dependencies (optional dependency + conditional bean), I also would like to offer conditional metrics. But I think there was just a misunderstanding from my side, cause`resilience4j-micrometer` seems to be using the Gradle equivalent to Maven `provided` scope, so it should all be sorted: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-micrometer/build.gradle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217390/discussion-between-rubasace-and-mark-bramnik).

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need any help on this, it looks like you've got it sorted ...